# Identify interrupted observations

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to identify missing observations that suggest cleaning/data errors.

My dataframe consists of many accounts over many years. Here are the rules it follows:

- Accounts may be **created or terminated**. In these cases, the amount is either $0 or NA. Such observations are (probably) not the result of bad data.
- Accounts **interrupted** by a NA or $0 are probably the result of bad data or cleaning errors.

In the data below, Accounts A-E show an amount for years 2001-2004.

```
df <- tribble(
       ~account,    ~"2001",     ~"2002",    ~"2003",  ~"2004",
       "Account.A",     100,          90,         87,       80,  #<Good   
       "Account.B",       0,          20,         30,       33,  #<Good
       "Account.C",      50,          55,          0,       0,   #<Good
       "Account.D",     200,         210,         NA,       210, #<Bad
       "Account.E",     150,           0,        212,       211) #<Bad
```

Account A,B,C show good data:

- Account A shows uninterrupted data
- Account B shows an account that began in 2002.
- Account C shows an account that expired in 2003 and remained $0 ever after.

Account D and E show bad data:

- Account D shows an account interupted in 2003
- Account E shows an account interrupted in 2002

My goal is to identify interrupted lines (D,E) and tag them.

I would like a solution that could be generalized across many years and thousands of accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` option that might not be the prettiest, but should do the trick:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  gather(year, value, `2001`:`2004`) %>% 
  group_by(account) %>% 
  mutate(order = if_else(year == min(year), 'first', 
                         if_else(year == max(year), 'last', 'mid'))) %>% 
  mutate(value = replace(value, is.na(value), 0)) %>% 
  mutate(start0 = row_number() >= min(row_number()[value != 0]),
         end0 = row_number() <= max(row_number()[value != 0])) %>% 
  mutate(check = if_else(order == 'mid' & value == 0 & start0 == TRUE & end0 == TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)) %>% 
  filter(check == TRUE)

# A tibble: 2 x 7
# Groups:   account [2]
  account   year  value order start0 end0  check
  <chr>     <chr> <dbl> <chr> <lgl>  <lgl> <lgl>
1 Account.E 2002      0 mid   TRUE   TRUE  TRUE 
2 Account.D 2003      0 mid   TRUE   TRUE  TRUE
```

Here's an explanation:

- Convert the data from wide to long.
- Determine, by group, whether an account entry is a first, middle, or last entry in its history.
- Because zeroes and NAs are treated the same, NAs are replaced with zeros to make this a   little easier to work with, but they could be kept as is and the code updated to handle them.
- TRUE/FALSE columns are added for whether a 0 value sequence runs from either the start or the end of the account history.
- If an account is 0, not a first or last entry, and not the part of a 0 sequence run from the beginning or end of the account history, the account is marked TRUE to check.
- Finally, there is a filter to only the accounts that need to be checked.

Comment: All of those mutate calls could be combined into one, I just happen to find it easier to follow if each step has its own call.

Comment: Agreed, not really sure what the real data look like so better to be safe with the `arrange()`. And it does work for zero start/end and also interrupted:  `df <- tribble(~account, ~"2001",  ~"2002", ~"2003", ~"2004", ~"2005", "Account.F", 0, 10, 0, 10, 10)` gets tagged to check. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you explain the "not part of a zero sequence" part? That is, the boolean `start0` and `end0`.

Comment: `start0` and `end0` look for the first non-zero values from the beginning and end of  each account. 0,0,10,10 would identify that the second zero is part of an opening zero sequence and should not be considered an interrupted, where as 0, 10, 0, 10 would be considered interrupted.